# mysqlimport or LOAD DATA INFILE with Multipoint datatype

Tags: mysql, mariadb, spatial, multipoint

I have a column in a table that has type [multipoint](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/multipoint/). How do I structure the data in my file to either use `mysqlimport` or the `LOAD DATA INFILE` construct to import this file?

Right now my data is in a plaintext json-formatted file (not in a database) and I would like to structure it to be compatible for import.

I am using MariaDB 15.1

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is all you need:

```
mysqldump --hex-blob ...
```

A subsequent reload using `mysql` should be able to exactly reconstruct the data.

`LOAD DATA` would need some extra code to deal with the conversion -- either geomFromText or unhex.  That should be possible; do you prefer `LOAD DATA`?

Comment: I added a clarification. My data is not in the database right now (otherwise, of course `mysqldump` would work). I need to structure it from a plaintext format to something that ideally `mysqlimport` or `LOAD DATA INFILE` could handle.

Comment: AsText, GeomFromText, HEX, UNHEX, --hex-blob, etc, work with ascii text.